# Can a shiny app output be tailored to an authenticated user?

Tags: authentication, shiny-server, shinyapps

I am new to coding and have been tinkering with the idea of making a shiny app to display data related to a pathogen. We receive samples from many companies and I would like them to be able to quickly access information from their own samples while keeping others anonymous. I know you can require authentication, but can you tie visibility to an individual user?

I have not tried to implement this yet, the authentication will only need to be specified for one tab.